# Remove single field from index mongod

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am unable to remove single field from index

> db.customer.getIndexes()

```
{
    "v" : 2,
    "unique" : true,
    "key" : {
        "customer_id" : 1
    },
    "name" : "customer_id_1",
    "background" : true,
    "ns" : "clarks-flo-live2.customer"
}
```

I am trying to remove **"unique" : true,** from above, please help me out.

Answer (score -2):

```
   db.customer.update(
       {"name" : "customer_id_1" },
       { $unset: { "unique" : true } }
    )
```

The specified value in the $unset expression (i.e. "") does not impact the operation.

To specify a  in an embedded document or in an array, use dot notation.

Behavior
If the field does not exist, then $unset does nothing (i.e. no operation).

When used with $ to match an array element, $unset replaces the matching element with null rather than removing the matching element from the array. This behavior keeps consistent the array size and element positions.

Comment: Hi 
I have tried but no luck,
db.customer.update(        {"name" : "customer_id_1" },        { $unset: { "unique" : true } }     );
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 0, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })

Comment: { $unset: { "unique" : true } } ,{multi :true} or { $unset: { "unique" : 1 } } ,{multi :true}      --Vote me

Comment: This would modify the matched documents, not the index like the OP needs.

Comment: -- ### click the link (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.dropIndex/).                                                                     
### :- Drops or removes the specified index from a collection. The db.collection.dropIndex() method provides a wrapper around the dropIndexes command. You cannot drop the default index on the _id field. To drop a text index, specify the index name.